# Removing whitespace and carriage return from a text file with Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, file

I am having a dataframe that contains 5 columns while doing data cleaning process i got a problem caused by the carriage return from the text file as shown in ***the exp below***.

**Input :**

```
001|Baker St.
London|3|4|7
002|Penny Lane
Liverpool|88|5|7
```

**Output:**

```
001|Baker St. London|3|4|7
002|Penny Lane Liverpool|88|5|7
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Carriage return is represented by `\r` while newline is `\n`, so replacing all `\r` with nothing should work.

Comment: Please replace images of text with actual text so we can copy it and use it. Also edit your question with your coding attempt as comments don’t format it correctly.

Comment: Hey Mark, ok it's done thanks

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `strip()` method that string objects provide does this; You can call it like this as you iterate over a line:

```
cleaned_up_line = line.strip()
```

As the [Python str.strip() docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) tell us, it also gets rid of whitespace, newlines, and other special characters - at the beginning and end of a string.

For example:

```
In [7]: with open('file', 'r') as f: 
   ...:     a = f.readlines() 
   ...:     print(a) 
   ...:                                                                                              
['the\n', 'file\n\r', 'is\n\r', 'here\n', '\n']

In [8]: with open('file', 'r') as f: 
   ...:     a = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()] 
   ...:     print(a) 
   ...:                                                                                              
['the', 'file', 'is', 'here', '']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `\r` like this:

```
with open("your.csv", "r") as myfile:
 data = myfile.read().replace('\r', '')
```

**Example:**

```
from io import StringIO

# second entry contains a carriage return \r
s = """91|AAA|2010|3
92|BB\rB|2011|4 
93|CCC|2012|5
"""

# StringIO simulates a loaded csv file:

# carriage return still there
StringIO(s).read()
# '91|AAA|2010|3\n92|BB\rB|2011|4\n93|CCC|2012|5\n'

# carriage return gone
StringIO(s).read().replace('\r', '')
# '91|AAA|2010|3\n92|BBB|2011|4\n93|CCC|2012|5\n'
```

**With Pandas:**

```
data = StringIO(StringIO(s).read().replace('\r', ''))
pd.read_csv(data, sep='|')

Out[35]: 
   91  AAA  2010  3
0  92  BBB  2011  4
1  93  CCC  2012  5
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwswer but i want to fix the carriage return only for specific row.(highlighted in yellow)

Answer (score 0):

You could match it with regex and remove it, i.e. `re.sub('[\r\n]', '', inputline)`.